# Is there a damage reduction for friendly fire on Valorant?

Tags: valorant

In Valorant you can damage your teammates (and take damage from them) using abilities (but not weapons). But it looks like friendly fire deals less damage (compared to the damage the enemies receive). Is that the case, and if so whats the damage reduction ratio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this website](https://techlistonline.com/valorant-friendly-fire-explained-the-pros-cons/), the abilities deals less damage when it's friendly fire, to 33%.

Quote (emphasized by me):

> Valorant abilities and ultimates can be used to do damage to friendlies. It’s important to mention that regular shooting will not do friendly fire. Despite that, players need to be careful when using their special abilities and ultimates because they can end up hurting their allies. In fact, there are many Valorant players that can get banned for friendly fire after griefing their teammates with abilities such as Pheonix’s “hot hands” for example. In addition, **damage done to friendlies and to yourself will be only 33% (including the burn rate of AoEs).**

Answer (score 2):

So can you kill your teammates in VALORANT? 
Aswer - Yes, and no.

1) No, you can’t shoot your team with any of the guns.

2) Yes, you can kill your teammates with your abilities. Such as with Raze’s bombs and ult, or for example, with Phoenix’s hot hand's ability. Any ability that does damage to the team will do damage to your teammates.

Accordingly, the damage is not reduced. It will be the same as the damage to your opponents. At least no one has officially spoken about this. This answer is based on tests and information by special Valorant sites.

Source:

https://gamepros.gg/valorant/articles/is-there-friendly-fire-team-damage-in-valorant

https://valoranttracker.org

https://www.polygon.com/valorant-guides-riot

https://heyyouvideogame.com/is-there-friendly-fire-in-valorant/

Comment: I'm like 99% sure that friendly fire abilities deal less damage since every time I got hit by razes jump bombs it did 3-8 dmg when shes on my team and 20-40 on the enemy team

Comment: Sova's shock dart does less damage to allies than to enemies....